# disappointed in/at the fact that

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to know which preposition to use in the following:

> We were disappointed **in**/**at** the fact that no one is interested in our products.

Comment: Related https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22990/is-it-disappointed-with-in-or-by

Comment: The sentence would be more natural _without_ 'fact'. We were disappointed to find no one is interested in our products. Or you could use 'to hear', 'to discover' or 'to learn' (followed, if you like, by 'that') instead of 'to find'. Is there some particular reason for wanting to use '_the fact_'?

Comment: Just curious about what preposition to use with "the fact." If you had to use "the fact," which preposition would you use?

Comment: Very wordy: would definitely advise "We were disappointed that no one is interested in our products". If you insist on using "the fact", use "by": "We were disappointed by the fact that no one is interested in our products"--but I strongly advise against that construction; feels very awkward & unnecessary... gives off big "trying to hit the word count requirement in 6th grade" vibes.

Answer (score 0):

I think for you to sound more grammatical, you can choose another word to use like "by". But if you want to choose between the two,pick "at"

Answer (score 0):

*Disappointed* is tricky: it can occur with any of several prepositions before the source of disappointment. Roughly:

- *disappointed **in*** someone: This suggests someone did something wrong or let you down.
- *disappointed **at***: To me this suggests a hint of surprise (like *surprised **at***).
- *disappointed **with**/**by***: Fairly generic ways of saying something disappointed you. **With** may emphasize that you consciously evaluated something and determined it was disappointing, rather than having the disappointment directly triggered in you by something external.

But these differences are subtle and probably not consistent across speakers. E.g., searching the web you can find plenty of restaurant reviews with "disappointed in/at/by/with the meal".

More discussion [here](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-correct-I-am-disappointed-in-you-or-I-am-disappointed-with-you).

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct. "At" is used to show the cause of something with adjective.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Your answer could be improved by explaining more and providing references. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).